# How to display hierarchy data with asp:Repeater from dataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, asprepeater

[How To pupulate like this use Asp:Repeater? Nested Repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uweEl.png)

[This is my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVHsn.png)

please help
thanks

Comment: First try on your own. Go to google type your problem there are 100 of solutions available. Stick to one. Then if you stuck anywhere ask here.

Comment: I've tried, I'm confused with the error "The relation is not parented".